# Lifecyle of a returned class constructor call

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class Value{
public:
int x;
Value(int y):x(y){
    
    }
};


Value getVal(){
  return Value(2);
}

int main() {


const Value & rec = getVal();
return 0;
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it safe to do this `return Value(2);` ?

   Does the created object expire once the functions ends ?
   If it does then how to properly receive it?
2. Why do I need to declare `const` if I am making a reference variable like on my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it safe to do this return `Value(2)`;

If you receive the return value as below then it's allowed (hence safe):

```
Value rec = getVal(); // also `const Value rec = getVal();`
```

or

```
const Value& rec = getVal();
```

With both the above cases, the scope of the variable is not destroyed and remains until the scope of the receiver i.e. `rec`.
Refer [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

> 2. Why do i need to declare const if i am making a reference variable?

Receiving by simple reference is not allowed.
As suggested in 1. you can also declare it as a simple variable. Compiler will not make unwanted copy. If you want to make `rec` as unmodifiable, then you may declare it as `const` reference.

Comment: So the `return Value(2)` is only temporary aswell? Because i get an error if i'll use pointer to receive it.

Comment: @CarloBrew, `Value(2)` on its own is temporary. But if it is  received in valid ways as suggested, then its scope remains until the scope of receiver, i.e. `rec`. Pointer is not possible because you cannot store an address of a temporary.

Comment: But when i try doing this  `Value * rec = &(getVal());`, it says  "[Error] taking address of temporary"